# Draw a tanh-ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods

The function $f(x,y)=\tanh(R-\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ for a given $R>0$ draws a circle with radius R with maximum and minimum of +1 and -1.

If I want to do the same, but draw an ellipsoid with major and minor axis *a* and *b*, then how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's investigate how $z = \tanh(R - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$ works.
For $x^2 + y^2 \ll R^2$ (inside the circle) the argument of $\tanh$ is a big positive value, thus the value of the function is about $1$. When the point is outside the circle $x^2 + y^2 \gg R^2$ the $\tanh$ argument is a big negative value, thus $\tanh$ is $-1$. For $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$ (the circle) both $\tanh$ and its argument are zeroes.

Let's start with ellipse equation
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1.
$$
Similarly, $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} < 1$ gives the ellipse interior, while $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} > 1$ gives its exterior. Thus
$$
g(x, y) = \tanh\left(1 - \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}}\right)
$$
may suit your needs. But when one sets $a = b = R$ we don't get the original formula. Thus we can scale $\tanh$ argument by $\sqrt{ab}$ to gen the desired limit case
$$
g(x, y) = \tanh\left(\sqrt{ab} - \sqrt{\frac{bx^2}{a} + \frac{ay^2}{b}}\right).
$$
The scaling of the $\tanh$ argument affects the speed of transition between the interior and the exterior ($1$ and $-1$ respectively).